# Visual Basic on excel object reqired

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this code on Excel VBA.  On one computer the code is running, and on other I got "object required" on these two lines:

```
CommonDialog1.InitDir = ThisWorkbook.Path
CommonDialog1.Filename = nameusr
```

I am using Excel 2003, but the file is saved in Excel 97-2003 format.

Comment: Have you checked that `CommonDialog1` is initialised? "Object required" usually means that you're trying to access a method or property of a nonexistent object. Also, `ThisWorkbook` is prone to errors since if it doesn't refer to the workbook that your code is expecting then your code will fail to find things.

Comment: Do you have any additional References selected in the workbook (Tools > References), and are any of them missing from the other computer?

Comment: I had check the additional References and nothing is missing.what do you mean:Have you checked that CommonDialog1 is initialised?